# JavaScript Dropdown - Click on button and redirect to url based on selected value

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have this form and now needed create a redirection after the user select the game type and slots on press the image button called "buynow.png".

If the user select "public" he will be redirected to "www.domain.com/public.html", otherwise if its "private" go to "www.domain.com/private.html"

Here the actual code

```
<div>
<form name="f1">
    <div>
        <select name="server_type" onchange="change_selection()">
            <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
            <option value="1">Public</option>
            <option value="2">Private</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select name="server_slots">
            <option value="-">-</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a><img src="images/bBuyNow.png" border="0" /></a>
    </div>
</form>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var slots_1=new Array("10 Players","11 Players","12 Players")
    var slots_2=new Array("10 Players","11 Players","12 Players")

    function change_selection(){
    var server_type
    server_type = document.f1.server_type[document.f1.server_type.selectedIndex].value
    if (server_type != 0) {
        slots_selected=eval("slots_" + server_type)
        cant_slots = slots_selected.length
        document.f1.server_slots.length = cant_slots
        for(i=0;i<cant_slots;i++){
        document.f1.server_slots.options[i].value=slots_selected[i]
        document.f1.server_slots.options[i].text=slots_selected[i]
    }
    }else{
        document.f1.server_slots.length = 1
        document.f1.server_slots.options[0].value = "-"
        document.f1.server_slots.options[0].text = "-"
    }
        document.f1.server_slots.options[0].selected = true
    }                                   
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you change the `window.location` in the `onchange` event of the 'public'/'private' `select` element, what exactly is the user meant to be doing with the 'server_slots' `select` element?

Comment: The "server_slots" is only for check a quantity from the server type, if the server is public have a price, but for private is other price. After that, depending on the preselected server type, when clic on button "BuyNow" they will be redirected to the order form in other url.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know what you are doing with slots but for redirection you can use `window.location.href`

```
      <div>
        <form name="f1">
            <div>
                <select name="server_type" onchange="change_selection()">
                    <option value="0" selected>Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Public</option>
                    <option value="2">Private</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select name="server_slots">
                    <option value="-">-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a><img src="images/bBuyNow.png" border="0" href="javascript:viod(0)" onclick="redirecturl();"/></a>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var slots_1=new Array("10 Players","11 Players","12 Players");
            var slots_2=new Array("10 Players","11 Players","12 Players");

            function redirecturl(){
            var server_type;
            server_type = document.f1.server_type[document.f1.server_type.selectedIndex].value;

var selectedslot = document.f1.server_slots[document.f1.server_slots.selectedIndex].value;
            if (server_type == 1) {
               window.location.href="www.domain.com/public.html?slot="+selectedslot ;
            }
            }else if(server_type == 2){
             window.location.href="www.domain.com/private.html?slot="+selectedslot;
            }
            else{
             alert('please select a value');
             return;
                }
            }                                   
        </script>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's a very simple pre order form where the user can check the prices for public service or private service. I check your code but nothing happend, remember, after the user select the server type and slots it's necesary to redirect to a new url based on the "server type" value by pressing the "BuyNow" image button.

Comment: how  you are passing slot type in url because i cannot the use of slot type in url :   is it like "www.domain.com/public/slot1.html"...?

Comment: @Kiwi:- see the updated answer.. i hope you are using slot as parameter in url.

Comment: Thanks, but when select the server type, the server_slots not fuction correctly and the button not redirect to any url.